# Connecting Pioneer Bluray/DVD burner via USB/SATA bridge in Debian

Tags: usb, debian, sata, dvd

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'm trying to connect my Pioneer BDR-209DBK to a Linux Mint (Debian Edition) box using a SATA to USB adapter.

The adapter is detected and

/var/log/messages shows:

```
usb 1-1.1.3: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
usb 1-1.1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa
usb 1-1.1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
usb 1-1.1.3: Product: ASMT1153e
usb 1-1.1.3: Manufacturer: asmedia
usb 1-1.1.3: SerialNumber: 12345678555
usb-storage 1-1.1.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
usb-storage 1-1.1.3:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 55aa: 400000
scsi8 : usb-storage 1-1.1.3:1.0
mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 10: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.3"
mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 10 was not an MTP device
usb 1-1.1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
```

Is it possible to access the drive using this adapter.  I'd just like to read DVDs if possible (no need to burn).

Comment: What is your actual problem with this?

Comment: How are you providing +5VDC and +12VDC power to the DVD drive?  The drive should be powered *before* you make the USB connection.

Comment: You deleted the timestamps, but if the reset happens very soon after detection that's usually not a good sign. If everything works, next you should see something like `scsi 8:0:0:0: CD-ROM ...`, and then `/dev/sgX` and `/dev/srX` devices attached to bus 8.. If you don't see it, the reset killed it. Not enough power is a possible reason for it not working.

Answer (score -1):

I issues with a ESATA to USB3 adapter `174c:55aa` and a Pioneer BDR-212U until I connected enclosure to ESATA, turned on enclosure and then connected USB3 to computer otherwise it would detect as a disk `/dev/sdX` rather than a cdrom `/dev/sr#` if I connected USB3 to ESATA adapter before turning on CD-ROM enclosure.

Also possibly needed `options usb-storage quirks=174c:55aa:u` in `/etc/modprobe.d/99-local.conf` so it wouldn't use UAS driver.